# Understanding the identity $f(x) \delta'(x-\xi) = - f'(\xi) \delta(x - \xi) + f(\xi) \delta'(x-\xi)$ in Fourier space

Tags: dirac-delta, schwartz-space

Consider the distributional identity (see Chapter 2.6 of Kanwal's Generalized Functions, for example)
$$
f(x) \delta'(x-\xi) = - f'(\xi) \delta(x - \xi) + f(\xi) \delta'(x-\xi) \tag{1}
$$
I can see how this identity must be true under and integral (using a test function $\phi(x)$), in that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x\ f(x) \delta'(x-\xi) \phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}x\ \big[ - f'(\xi) \delta(x - \xi) + f(\xi) \delta'(x-\xi) \big] \phi(x) \ .
$$

I am curious if there is a way to understand the equation (1) in Fourier space *ie.* is there a way to see that
$$
f(x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi} i p e^{i p (x - \xi)} = - f'(\xi) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi} e^{i p (x - \xi) } + f(\xi) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi} i p e^{i p (x - \xi)}
$$
*without* putting the LHS and RHS underneath an integral with a test function?

**P.S.** Although this argument is probably in bad taste, I can for example make some progress on the identity $x \delta(x) = 0$ in Fourier space:
$$
x\delta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi} x e^{i p x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} p} \left\{ - i e^{i p x} \right\} \to 0
$$
which is zero if you can ignore the contribution from the endpoints. So I am looking for something analogous here.

Comment: It is quite a bad habit to write $\int_{-\infty}^∞ e^{ixy}\, \mathrm d y$ since it is not a well defined integral, and just means $\delta_0$, which is a much simpler object.